# Driver for Windows 10 Eye Control

Tags: windows, winapi, eye-tracking

Windows 10 eye-control feature supports various eye-tracker devices.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-started-with-eye-control-in-windows-1a170a20-1083-2452-8f42-17a7d4fe89a9#bkmk_setup_win10

However, my question is, is it possible to create a driver for a new eye-tracker device not on the above list.

I am developing an eye-tracker as part of my research and would like to create a driver for the new device such that it will work with windows 10 eye control...

Would someone be able to throw light on the whether this is possible...???

Comment: It's quite a pit you go down into if you try to find any documentation on how to create any drive for any kind of hardware.